# Headset mic not working on Ubuntu at Xiaomi Redmibook

Tags: sound, headset

I've bought a [HyperX CloudX - Gaming Headset](https://hyperx.com/products/hyperx-cloud-xbox?variant=41031690780829), but I can't get it working on Ubuntu.

The headset works perfectly works out of the box on a different Windows box.

I've tried editing alsa-base.conf. Here is the current version, I've also tried "auto" which didn't do good.

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi,headset-mic,headset-mode,headphone-mic-pin
```

I edited jacks with hdajackrestack. 18 and 19 ports are now overridden to microphone. It helped get the option menu (headphones/headset/mic) when connecting the headset. The mic is seen by the machine, but not recording any sound. pavucontrol sees the mic as well, but it is silent there too. It has 3 options - internal mic and headset are plugged out,
and the one microphone is plugged in but silent.

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic],
device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
Subdevices: 0/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 IOMMU 00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:01.7 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus A
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61) 00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation XG6 NVMe SSD Controller
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c2) 
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1 
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1 
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
```

cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
HD-Audio Generic at 0xc07c8000 irq 118
1 [Generic_1      ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
HD-Audio Generic at 0xc07c0000 irq 119

```
lspci -v | grep -i audio

03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor
    Subsystem: Xiaomi ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
```

Comment: try unmute mic with ``alsamixer'' command

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Do you know what sound card you have on your machine?

Comment: @petep it's not present in alsamixer somehow. i don't have mic option, only mic boost. maxing it out doesn't help, and it's not muted

Comment: @moo lunar 23.04. I've added some commands output to the question, what may lead to soundcard info. Sorry, I'm very bad at hardware part, so if you can tell how to get that info - i'll appreciate

Comment: change the sound card with F6 key in alsamixer then unmute

Comment: There's nothing to unmute. Microphone is not present on any sound card at alsamixer.

Comment: If it's a USB headset (I don't think it is) or USB audio interface, try `lsusb`. If it's plugged into your motherboard/laptop, provide the model of those (and then we can try and match it up with the output of `lspci`)

Comment: @moo it's plugged in with jack. Soundboard is realtec ALC256M and laptop model is Xiaomi RedmiBook 14-APCS 2019 (Ryzen edition)